# Select a polygon layer where a line touches its boundary more than 1 time

Tags: arcmap, attribute-joins, select

My problem is that I don't know how to select the layers (polygons) where the lines touches the boundarys twice or more. I have tried to illustrate this in the picture.

(see image) 
I am using arcmap desktop advanced

Any tip or workaround?

[image: Example results]

Comment: arcmap desktop pro and arcGIS pro. Have booth

Comment: Are you trying to do this in ArcMap or in ArcGIS Pro?  What precisely have you tried?

Comment: Questions which request answers using multiple software solutions are treated the same as Questions asking multiple questions (closed as *too broad*). Please **edit** the question to specify exactly one software solution. The fact that the data is corrupt  could also be interpreted as an additional question, since the obvious solution intersections which are multipart) would not apply to invalid input.

Comment: To be clear. I am only doing it in arcmap advanced.